# Short MEF issue regarding PartCreationPolicy.Any and ServiceLocator.GetInstance()

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, prism, mef

Just wanted to know if what I'm trying to do is possible since I couldn't find any information about it in the net.

Lets say I got a class that I export with PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.Any).
If I'd like to import it with ServiceLocator.Instance.GetInstance(), where can I specify with which CreationPolicy I'd like to import it? (If it would be Shared or NonShared)

Just couldn't find any info about it anywhere.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand it this can't be specified through a generic service locator.

By default, `CreationPolicy.Any` will be treated as 'shared'. To get a 'non-shared' instance you need to either:

- Change the creation policy on the part to `CreationPolicy.NonShared`; or,
- Use the MEF `CompositionContainer.GetExports(ImportDefinition)` method; or,
- Create a part that uses an `ExportFactory` import and request that from the `ServiceLocator` (see below. Requires MEF 2, or Silverlight 4 - not available in the .NET 4.0 RTM MEF.)

The kind of thing you need for the third option would look like:

```
[Export]
public class ExportFactoryProvider<T>
{
    [Import]
    public ExportFactory<T> Factory { get; set; }
}
```

Then, request one of these from the service locator and use the factory property to create new instances (where `IService` is the thing you want to instantiate new instances of):

```
var serviceFactory =
    ServiceLocator.Instance.GetService<ExportFactoryProvider<IService>>();

using (var service1 = serviceFactory.Factory.CreateExport())
{
    DoSomething(service1.Value);
}
```

Admittedly this ends up looking a bit hacky. I believe the reason for the awkwardness is that few (no?) other IoC containers support specifying anything like `CreationPolicy` when a service is requested.